# Class TLargeintField not found

Tags: c++builder, unidac, uniquery

I'm using C++ Builder 2009.

I've been doing some international work on one of my projects. I've upgraded my query components to UniQuery components and all of my db connections to UniDAC. Now when I run my program, some of the forms will throw some exceptions when the form is being created.

```
Project X.exe raised exception class EClassNotFound with message 'Class TLargeintField not found'.
```

Doing some reading online, some suggestions were to remove all of the fields in the query component and readd them, which I did and still get the same messages. I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong, or if I need to add a reference to the VCL? http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TLargeintField.html

**Additional Info:**

Below is a screenshot of the error message.

[image]

Based on the error message, it makes me feel like I might have a reference to the header file properly, but not referencing the lib file properly.

I beleive the header file for the VCL would be in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\include\vcl
```

I've tried adding the following into the lib path and it still can't find the class:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\lib\release
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\6.0\lib\psdk
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the root cause of the issue. This particular issues is related to korzh translation tool in which after you make changes to the form, you need to refresh the language files. This process runs the compiler multiple times and from what I can tell, updates different dfm's for each of the files. This message was coming across when my region settings were set to Itailian (Italy), and looked to be referencing an old dfm. After refreshing the languages, it looks like my other attempts (removing then readding the fields to the UniQuery componenets), solved the issue...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly then DAC wants to have `TLargeIntFile` fields for calculated values for example, but when adding fields to query then they are created as normal integers.

In my case I just modified the .dfm formfile and changed the field type manually:

```
object QMinutes: TLargeintField
```

Comment: Thanks Riho, I found out the root cause of my issue and posted my solution below. Gave you an up vote for the appreciated info.